# TextView does not show the message

Tags: android, textview

So, Im trying to show how many characters has in the string that I'm receving for one entrance.

This is string is going to message. But the problem is, if I put this line

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
```

, It doesnt show the string and it shows the already set string. If I remove this line, the code works but only shows one textView, the second doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();

    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);

    textView.setText(message);

    setContentView(textView);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
    //until here everything is working

    TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytextview);
    myTextView.setText("My double value is ");
```

I have the ID mytextview on the xml file.

Comment: you inflate a layout again and initialize another textview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need

```
String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setTextSize(40);
textView.setText(message);
setContentView(textView);
```

You can use `textView.append(value); textView.append("\n")` instead of inflating a layout

OR You only need

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
Intent intent = getIntent();
String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytextview);
myTextView2.append("My double value is ");
myTextView2.append("\n"); // new line
myTextView.append(message);
```

Assuming activity_display_message.xml has a textview with id mytextView

If you need another textview

```
TextView myTextView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytextview2);
// need to have another textview with id mytextview2 in activity_display_message.xml
myTextView2.setText("My double value is ");
```

But instead you can use append with a single textview

Comment: I want to show the second information on the screen, this only gonna show the string. itself

Comment: @user3255951 that's why i said use append instead of setText. there is no need for another textview at all. If you need another then initialize one more instead of inflating a layout

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Im still learning java, Im sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

You should paste both of your text views into layout xml:

```
  Intent intent = getIntent();

    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
    //until here everything is working

    TextView myTextView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytextview1);
    myTextView1.setText(message);

    TextView myTextView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytextview2);
    myTextView2.setText("My double value is ");
```

Comment: Many thanks too @Dimmerg, gonna try your solution too. Looks more simple and clarified.